# Are arrays initialized like `float[10][10]` already memory aligned for SIMD/SSE?

Tags: c++, sse, simd

I need to optimize my matrix multiplication by using SIMD/Intel SSE. The example code given looks like:

```
*x = (float*)memalign(16, size * sizeof(float));
```

However, I am using C++ and `[found that][1]` I instead of `malloc` (before doing SIMD), I should use `new`. Now, I'm further optimizing via SIMD/SSE, so I need aligned memory, so question is: do I need `memalign`/`_aligned_malloc` or is my array declared like

```
static float m1[SIZE][SIZE];
```

already aligned? (`SIZE` is an int)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Typically, they would not be 16-byte aligned, although there is nothing in the C++ specification that would prevent your compiler from aligning such an array on a 16-byte boundary. Depending upon what compiler you're using, there is usually a compiler-specific way to request that the array be aligned on a 16-byte boundary. For example, for `gcc`, you would use:

```
static float m1[SIZE][SIZE] __attribute__((aligned(16)));
```

Alternatively, you could use `posix_memalign()`, `memalign()`, or other aligned-allocation APIs available on your platform to get a block of memory with the desired alignment. As a worst case, you could even allocate memory using standard `malloc()` or `operator new` and then handle the alignment adjustment yourself.

Comment: I'm using `g++` its the same I suppose? I mean `gcc` is for C and `g++` is for C++? Since I am using C++ then I do that for `g++`? I'll try that.

Comment: The `gcc` front end actually supports both C and C++. It will switch modes based upon the extension of the source file (i.e. it will expect a `.c` file to be C and `.cc` or `.cpp` files to be C++). If you want to be C++-explicit, then you can invoke it as `g++` instead.

Comment: Note also that SIZE will need to be a multiple of 4 if you want each array row to be aligned (I assume that both you and the OP are aware of this - I just add it for any future readers of this question).

Comment: Hmm, now I need to allocate memory on the heap instead ... I think I will need to convert to `float* m1 = new float[SIZE*SIZE]` how does the `__attribute__((aligned(16)))` part fit in now?

Comment: If you're allocating from the heap, you would use one of the `memalign()`-like functions, like the ones you noted in your original question. You wouldn't want to use `operator new` in this case, unless you've overridden it to allocate the underlying memory using one of the aligned facilities.